# Automated testing of Salesforce Oauth flow breaking by "verify your identity in salesforce" process

Tags: oauth

I don't have the rep to comment on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120531/is-there-any-way-around-verification-code-i-am-using-selenium-and-java-to-auto), so I'll have to add my own.

I want to automate testing of the SF Oauth server auth flow. I can go through it manually, and everything works, but when I run my test (Selenium, [chromedriver](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/classes/ChromeDriver.html), using the same credentials, I get an email with the title "Verify your identity in Salesforce", which contains (redacted) this:

> You recently logged in to Salesforce from a device we don't recognize.
>
> Browser: Chrome Operating System: Linux Username: [email]
>
> To ensure your account's security, we need to verify your identity.
>   Enter the following code where prompted by Salesforce.
>
> Verification Code: [code]

I take screenshots throughout the process. My screenshot for after I click on the Salesforce oauth window's "Login" button does not show anything, other than the form.

I don't think this is due to Multi-factor auth, which is not set on my account. I think it's happening because Salesforce does some "bot check", recognizes my test is not a 'real user', and triggers the email. My screenshots don't show any alert or new window, so even if I went to the trouble of getting the email programatically, I wouldn't know how to use the verification code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce shows that screen on the basis of your ip. so if you want to bypass that screen create a new profile specific only for selenium test and Add ip range on that specific profile from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 and run your selenium test.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I get to that screen?

Comment: You can enble advanced profle from setup->customozes->user interface