# How to bypass verification code for selenium testing

Tags: selenium

I am new to use selenium to test Salesforce. It seems to me it is opening browser in a completely new session which requires login and verification code. And I need to skip the verification code to make it work.

Since it is using a completely new session it is requiring email verification every time and the trusted IP range approach doesn't seem to work for me: Salesforce just doesn't accept 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. I am just wondering how to walk around this issue.

Comment: Does not accept on Company level or Profile level? Just made that working on profile level and able to auth without access token

Comment: Check this answer, its talking about having a separate user/profile and having this permission turned off- `Two-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins`- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/120539/4726